# Applying custom 'core' phtml files to a theme

Tags: magento2, theme, phtml

In Magento 1 if I wanted to modify my own version of a phtml file I would move it into the theme directory, while maintaining the same structure. I have needed to do this on a single Magento instance that has multiple store views and uses different themes.

An example would be

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

Being added into

```
app/design/frontend/argento/<my_theme>/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

When viewing the website, my updated template would be used and not affect any other store views I have.
This method didn't require any xml updates, or technical wizardry, which suited me perfectly.

---

Magento 2 seems to be structure quite differently
The breadcrumbs file is held within

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

A slider file is here

```
app/code/Swissup/EasySlide/view/frontend/templates/slider.phtml
```

Where would these need to be placed to display using my own theme, which is below

```
/app/design/frontend/Local/<my_theme>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite in **module template** file in **custom theme**

```
/app/design/frontend/Namespace/<my_theme>/Swissup_EasySlide/templates/slider.phtml
```

*Note:: some time need to move the layout file too*

```
/app/design/frontend/Namespace/<my_theme>/Swissup_EasySlide/layout/
```

*run this cmd **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy***

Comment: Perfect ... the 'Swissup_EasySlide' is now working :)
Can you also tell me where I would put
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

Comment: Just remove view/frontend folder from structure rest is same